# I am familiar with the Monroe Motivated Sequence, which is used for speeches. What are some other frameworks which make the outlining process easier?

Tags: planning, outline

I am familiar with the Monroe Motivated Sequence, which is used to persuade people to take an action. This may be utilized in a speech or a piece of writing. I am interested in learning about other frameworks and templates which make the outlining process easier within the realm of writing: informational, persuasive, or otherwise. If an infographic exists on any of these techniques, I would be delighted if someone can share this with us.

Comment: hello! welcome to Writer's SE.  I wrote an answer with speculation to what you are asking for but I find it a little unclear of what you are looking for specifically... as it stands now, it seems a bit open ended for all forms of writing... so many categories have so many varying ways within a subject to write them.  Poetry alone has many many forms/templates/rules.  Scholarly writing has their own conventions.  What are you looking to gain from the answers?

Comment: @ggiaquin - Thank you for your response! Models such as "Freytag's Pyramid" and "Monroe's Motivated Sequence" exist and have in fact helped me structure my writing, whether it was fiction, or non-fictional. Therefore, I am quite certain that other models exist, as well. As for your question on what I am looking to gain, I think it's self-evident in my question that I am looking to collect quick templates to which I can refer to to give structure to my writings.

Comment: What kind of writing are you looking to outline/structure? Speeches? Persuasive essays? Blog posts? Novels? Poetry? as @ggiaquin notes, this is very broad right now. If you can narrow this down to "templates for writing a speech" or "templates for structuring a novel," the community might be better able to help you.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I am mostly interested in (1). Persuasive essays (2). Calls to action, and (3). Feature pieces on new technology

Comment: Please provide a link to the framework you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a great many systems for structuring the argument of a piece of writing. Each taking different approach to what to structure and how. Some to check out include:

- [Information mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_mapping)
- [STOP](http://www.hyperwrite.com/Articles/showarticle.aspx?id=85)
- [DITA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Information_Typing_Architecture)
- [Minimalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalism_(technical_communication))
- [Inverted pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid)

In addition you should look at structured writing generally (you can check out my series on [Structured Writing](https://techwhirl.com/series/structured-writing/), which will soon become a book).

Also, you should notice that common template exist for expressing all kinds of content. Recipies, for instance, have a well known format that almost everyone follows, and the same is true for many other subjects. If you browse Wikipedia you will notice that there are common templates emerging for articles on all kinds of subjects.

Comment: Excellent! Finally, a coherent answer! You mentioned that on Wikipedia, "there are common templates emerging for articles on all kinds of subjects." Could you please point me to these templates? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know that the templates are formalized, though some of them may be. But my point was that people writing about one city, for instance, copy things that other people have done in writing about another city, and the more such copying takes place, the more a common pattern emerges. The Wikipedia edit process makes it kind of an organic template factory, but AFAIK it is template by example.